# Error when compiling via g++ on terminal on Mavericks

Tags: c++, gcc

I used g++ compiler and used terminal for compiling single c++ files and projects as well (under project I mean files in the same dir, but not a real Xcode project).
I had no problems, but I upgraded to OS X Mavericks, and from that point, I am only able to compile single files. After that, I installed Xcode 5.0.1, and installed command line tools, but didn't solve my problem.

So now I am using
OS X 10.9 Mavericks
Xcode 5.0.1 (5A2053).

I thought, the problem is with my source code, but now I've made a really simple program, but I get the same error:

```
Steve-MacBook:test szaboistvan$ g++ -o main main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Myclass::geta()", referenced from:
      _main in main-0bDtiC.o
  "Myclass::getb()", referenced from:
      _main in main-0bDtiC.o
  "Myclass::Myclass()", referenced from:
      _main in main-0bDtiC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The files of the project:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Myclass.h"
using namespace std;



int main(){

    Myclass one;
    cout<<one.geta()<<endl<<one.getb()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Myclass.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Myclass
{
private:
    int a;
    double b;
public:
    Myclass();
    int geta();
    double getb();
};
```

Myclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Myclass.h"
using namespace std;

Myclass(){
    int a=5;
    double b=3.0;
}

int geta(){
    return a;
}

double getb(){
    return b;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You say "After that, I installed Xcode 5.0.1, and installed command line tools, but didn't solve my problem" but Xcode doesn't include `gcc` so you'd have to use `clang`, but you don't say that, which makes me believe you carried on using `g++`...

Comment: @trojanfoe Xcode does include GCC, that is not the problem.

Comment: @OP: the error is entirely obvious, you don't compile/link the `MyClass.cpp` file. (Honnan tudná szerencsétlen gcc, hogy melyik fájlokat fordítsa, ha nem adod meg neki!?)

Comment: Oh, and this hasn't quite anything to do with Xcode or OS X Mavericks.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's true; `gcc` is an alias for `clang`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am being thick (hint, I am not), you havent implemented

`MyClass::geta()`.
Instead, you implemented  a function called `geta`

Your class methods should be like:

```
MyClass::Myclass()
{
    int a=5;
    double b=3.0;
}

int MyClass::geta()
{
    ....
}
```

etc

In addition, you cant be compiling `MyClass.cpp`, since the code in there is not valid.